# Переделать итеративную функцию в рекурсивную

Tags: c, функции, рекурсия

Есть вот такая функция:

```
int AvsB(char *string1,char *string2){
int i,length=stringLength(string1);
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        if(convertInInt(string1[i])>convertInInt(string2[i])){//A>B
            return printf("%s > %s",string1,string2);
        }
        if(convertInInt(string1[i])<convertInInt(string2[i])){//A<B
            return printf("%s < %s",string1,string2);
        }
        if(convertInInt(string1[i])==convertInInt(string2[i])&&i==length-1){//A==B
            return printf("%s = %s",string1,string2);
        }
    }
}
```

Она сравнивает два числа, которые введены как строки.
Нужно передалать ее используя рекурсию.

Как я понимаю - решением будет находить длину строки до вызова функции в программе и передавать это значение как параметр функции.

И счетчик для получение следущего элемента строки - `i` нужно также передавать параметром ?

Или есть более правильный подход ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция должна нести ответственность за *одно действие*, т.е. не должна она сравнивать и еще и выводить сообщение.

Вынесем вывод, тогда получится что-то типа

```
int AvsB(char *string1,char *string2)
{
    if ((*string1 == 0) && (*string2 == 0)) return 0;
    if(convertInInt(*string1)>convertInInt(*string2))
    {   //A>B
        return 1;
    }
    if(convertInInt(string1[i])<convertInInt(string2[i])){//A<B
        return -1
    }
    return AvsB(string1+1,string2+1);
}

int res = AvsB(string1,string2);
printf("%s %c %s\n",string1,(res == 1) ? '>' : (res == -1) ? '<' : '=', string2);
```

Примерно так. Сравниваем первые символы, если не равны - ответ получен, равны - сравниваем строки, получающиеся отбрасыванием первых символов. Первая проверка - на окончание строк.

Смысл `convertInInt()` для меня остается загадкой, но если вы считаете, что он там нужен... :)